# Acrobat Reader by playonlinux: Error in POL_Wine

Tags: playonlinux, adobe-acrobat

I installed **Acrobat Reader DC** (2015 version) on **Ubuntu 16.04** by **playonlinux**. It works fine but if I call it by command line:

```
playonlinux --run Adobe\ Acrobat\ Reader\ DC mypdffile.pdf
```

**when I close the program** I got: `Error in POL_Wine`

[image]

despite I can regularly use the software, this is very annoyng. How can I remove this error message?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: @MLC No I didn't.